# angular-ui ui-router controller not getting instantiated with $state.go

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am trying to build an app which on login changes the state to a view with $state.go but when calling $state.go the controller is not instantiated as defined for that state.

Here is my state change logic (removing other code for brevity):

```
config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider
  .state('login', {
    url: "/",
    templateUrl: "templates/login.html",
    controller: 'LoginController'
  })
  // setup an abstract state for the tabs directive
  .state('tab', {
    url: "/tab",
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: "templates/tabs.html"
  })

  // Each tab has its own nav history stack:
  .state('tab.dash', {
    url: '/dash',
    views: {
      'tab-dash': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-dash.html',
        controller: 'DashboardController'
      }
    },
    resolve: {
      authenticated: ['RestService', function(restService) {
        return restService.authenticationStatus();
      }],
      sessionService: ['SessionService', function(sessionService) {
        return sessionService;
      }]
    }
  })
```

My LoginController is something like:

```
  // Perform the login action when the user submits the login form
  $scope.doLogin = function(loginForm) {
    if (loginForm.$invalid) {
        $log.debug('Invalid Form...', $scope.loginData);
        return;
    }
    $log.debug('Doing login', $scope.loginData);

    RestService.login($scope.loginData)
      .then(function(data) {
          $log.debug("Inside loginController...");
          $log.debug(data);
          $scope.$state.go("tab.dash");
      }, function(data) {
          $log.debug(data);
          $scope.formErrors = data.errors;
      });
  };
```

And my DashboardController is something like:

```
angular.module('starter.controller.dashboard', [])

.controller('DashboardController', ['$scope', '$log', '$http',
  function($scope, $log, $http) {
    $log.debug("reaching here..................");
    $log.debug($scope.authenticated);
```

}]);

Now when the login succeeds, the state is transitioned to /tab/dash but the controller is not instantiated i.e. the debug logs in DashboardController are not printed. If I directly navigate to /tab/dash then the controller does get instantiated and I do see the logs getting printed.

Moreover the value of "authenticated" passed via resolve in state definition is not available via scope in templates.

Comment: @JB Nizet: No I have added the 'starter.controller.dashboard' to the dependency of my main module and I am not seeing any errors in console. Moreover as stated in my question, if I navigate to state directly then the controller does get instantiated. If there was any error in dependency resolution, it should have shown error in console even when directly navigating to the state.

Comment: what does the code for `authenticationStatus()` look like? Resolves must complete *before* the controller is initialized, so the problem is likely in that function....

Comment: @Claies: Even if I change the resolve to:

resolve: {
      authenticated: function(restService) {
        return true;
      }
    }

I still see the same behaviour.

Comment: does the controller initialize if you do not have a resolve option at all?

Comment: @Claies: No even after I remove the resolve option, still I don't see the DashController getting initialized.

Comment: reading the documentation on `$state.go()`, I suspect you may need to pass a parameter to reload the route, something like `$scope.$state.go("tab.dash", {} ,{reload:true});`

Comment: No even with these extra parameters passed, I still see the controller not getting instantiated.

Comment: does it have something to do with the fact that `$state.go()` returns a promise, and you are trying to execute it from another promise?

Comment: @Claies: My understanding of promises is little limited and I am not sure what is causing this. :(

Answer (score 0):

Well turns out that the controller is getting instantiated but it gets instantiated only once. If I don't refresh the page while testing and just change the path then since the controller is already instantiated, it is not instantiated again. Only if I refresh the page (LoginPage) and then navigate to Dashboard page (via $state.go on logging in) the controller gets instantiated again.

And the issue with resolve data not available in the controller is because my assumption was that it is auto injected in $scope but actually it is not so. The resolve params get injected explicitly via the passed params to constructor function of controller and then one needs to assign the values manually in the scope. Something like:

```
.controller('DashboardController', ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$log', '$ionicLoading', '$http', 'authenticated',
  function($rootScope, $scope, $log, $ionicLoading, $http, authenticated) {
    $scope.authenticated = authenticated;
}]);
```